# Mobile Site ignores meta=viewport and is zooming-in any thumb or content

Tags: css, mobile, web, viewport, meta

It seems everything I add as meta to work for mobile version of the site , it is actually ignored and is full-zoomed ( when I visit my site on a mobile ) to the actual size of what I have in CSS.

```
>  I tried :
>  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,> initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"> & 
>  <meta name="viewport"> content="width=device-width">
```

As a matter of fact, I completely took off that line in hope it will not scale, but it still zoom-in !

The header, seems to be ok, and is scaling good on mobile , but everything else, is zoomed-in .

Exemple : thumb is 728x410 in css , yet , with or without the mobile meta viewport , it still have the same size on mobile which makes it huge!

Also, when the website is loading on mobile, the actual meta=viewport works , meaning if I have set to have a 320 px on mobile, the thumbs does show as it should , but when website is fully loaded, bum .. back to 728px which i have in css!

Anyone knows how to fix this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having built many responsive websites, I have to state that if you have content wider than the mobile screen (in this case 320px, Iphone only?), it will mess everything up.
To solve this, make sure you have a few main wrappers around your content like a `header`, `content` and `footer` div.
Give these divs the following css rules when on mobile:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .header,.content,.footer{
    display:block;
    position: relative /*for absolute positioning or to get them behind
                         pop-ups with z-index
                         this also prevents absolute-position elements being outside
                         the parent element from stretching the view*/
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
  }
}
```

The above should prevent anything from messing up your scaling. From there, you can see which elements don't fit and style them accordingly.

Also, if you want to disallow zooming, you have to put in `user-scalable=0`, like so:

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,
user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
```

Make sure your content actually scales down to your phone's screen size. It will make a major difference. I would also personally recommend you to get used to using `box-sizing:border-box;`. This means adding any padding or borders to any elements be *taken off the element* rather than being *added to the element*.

example: Your screen is 320px wide. You have a `<div width="320"></div>`, it will be 320px wide. Adding `padding:20px` to it, will make it `360px` wide (`20px` padding to both sides)

However, using `box-sizing:border-box` will make sure it stays at `320px` (same with 100% width) and instead, the content will be fit within the leftover `280px`.  Just a tip.

also: What kind of media queries are you using in your CSS file?

**Update specifically for your website**
I got it to be like this:
--img removed for privacy reasons --

These are the css changes I've made **including adding the meta tag in my answer to your head, replacing yours**:

```
#headerContent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#mainContainer {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.videoListItem .thumb img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%!important;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: -68px;
    left: 0;
}

#leftColumn {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.videoListItem .thumb .playIcon {
    background: url(./images/play_icon.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 86px;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-left: -43px;
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer! Your viewport actually do the same as I said in my post , meaning that when is actually loading, all thumbs, text, etc are OK , but when the load is completed , it's back to full CSS size. I am pretty sure it's something in the CSS which does this ! I think this is what it's causing the issue `.videoListItem .thumb {
    position: relative;
    height: 410px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}
.videoListItem .thumb img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -68px;
    left: 0;
}`

Comment: Hello! To test this out, could you give `.videoListItem` these css rules: `width:100%; overflow:hidden;`? It should give you a valid test result and then we can delve into the issue further. If you have a live example of your website, that'd be perfect. this most definitely seems like a CSS issue and not a meta tag one. We can't see your CSS from here.

Comment: Still the same! Ah! So it seems it's not from .videoListItem

Comment: Actually, it's from many things. I fixed it, kind of... in 30 seconds.
you have many elements that are too wide. Look for them!
You have no specific mobile-css rules for `#leftColumn`, which has a static width of 728. Same for `#mainContainer`, which has a static width of 1074px. Your meta tag is also wrong. You should use the one I just gave you.

Then there's the `.videoListItem .thumb .playIcon`. To make it center dynamically, just put it on `left:50%, margin-left-100px; /*make this half of the button's own width*/.

Seems like you have a lot to do. I can't build all your css for you.

Comment: I have updated my answer with all the css changes I made to get the result I included in my answer. Does that make things more clear?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! This actually fixed some things , but it seems I still need to work more in order to have a desktop and a mobile version of the site , within one website ! I don't know how you managed to have that thumbs showing in your screens , but at me it shows half image and half black! Also, when I press on a link, it's ... pretty big there too ! Anyway , will look at this for another 30 mins and then I will go to sleep! European here and 15 mins ago was a .. pretty earthquake here , in Italy :) EDIT: Another one! C"mon!!! :)

Comment: Good luck with the earthquakes. I live in the same time zone, so I kind of understand. Yes, I forgot a bit of css to shrink those down, sorry. But you just need to use your inspector and find these elements. I'm sorry but I can't help you do the entire website ^^. If you think this is the best answer you can get, please accept it so that people know the matter is closed ^^